# All changes are going to the same fragment, why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating a battleship game where player1 sees his ships in the bottom screen and the top screen is where he makes moves on player2's board. But everything keeps being sent to player1 screen. So all the player1 ships and all the moves against player2 are all showing up in `_p1BattleshipFragment`. Is this a limitation of fragments, or have I used the wrong fragment name somewhere (even though I've looked at my code for hours trying to figure out why), or somehow am I sending everything to that fragment without realizing it? I need a fresh pair of eyes and/or an explanation of what exactly I'm doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public static final String GAME_INDEX_EXTRA = "game_index";
int _gameIndex = -1;

Game _currentGame;
BattleshipFragment _p2BattleshipFragment;
BattleshipFragment _p1BattleshipFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(rootLayout);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra(GAME_INDEX_EXTRA))
    {
        _gameIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(GAME_INDEX_EXTRA);

        if(_gameIndex != -1)
            _currentGame = GameLibrary.getInstance().getGame(_gameIndex);
        else
            _currentGame = new Game();

    }
    else
    {
        finish();
    }

    FrameLayout p2_screen = new FrameLayout(this);
    p2_screen.setId(10);
    rootLayout.addView(p2_screen, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 49));

    View divider = new View(this);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    rootLayout.addView(divider, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 2));

    FrameLayout p1_screen = new FrameLayout(this);
    p1_screen.setId(11);
    rootLayout.addView(p1_screen, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 49));


    _p2BattleshipFragment = new BattleshipFragment();
    _p1BattleshipFragment = new BattleshipFragment();

    FragmentTransaction addTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    addTransaction.add(10, _p2BattleshipFragment);
    addTransaction.add(11, _p1BattleshipFragment);
    addTransaction.commit();

    p2_screen.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {
            _currentGame.gameState = "In Progress";

            int id = _p2BattleshipFragment._currentViewId;
            int x = 0;
            int y = id;
            int value = 0;
            if(y > 10)
            {
                x = id/10;
                y = id%10;
            }
            value = _currentGame.markHit(_currentGame.p2, x, y);

            switch(value)
            {
                case -1: // hit
                    _p2BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 0: // already guessed
                    break;
                case 10: // miss
                    _p2BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case 100: // sunk ship
                    break;
                case 1000: // game over
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    int[][] board = _currentGame.p1._board;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            int id = 0;
            try
            {
                String idString = Integer.toString(j) + Integer.toString(i);
                id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            int value = board[i][j];
            switch (value)
            {
                case -1: // hit
                    _p1BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 0: // already guessed
                    _p1BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case 1: // miss
                    _p1BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    int[][] board2 = _currentGame.p2._board;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            int id = 0;
            try
            {
                String idString = Integer.toString(j) + Integer.toString(i);
                id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            int value = board2[i][j];
            switch (value)
            {
                case -1: // hit
                    _p2BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 0: // already guessed
                    _p2BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case 1: // miss
                    _p2BattleshipFragment.setColor(id, Color.GRAY);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

There is no xml because this is an assignment and that was part of the instruction - everything is to be done programmatically.

Comment: Your code is confusing (at the very least it isn't Java convention to use underscore as a prefix for variables). Also why create your layout in code? It's easier to do what you need with an XML layout file and you could remove the code. Also Fragments should be self-contained - don't set touch listeners on the FrameLayouts in your Activity - let the Fragments handle their own touch events and communicate with the Activity using callback interface methods. This would ensure each Fragment would get the right event and handle it's own UI updates.

Comment: The use of the underscore as a prefix was because that's how my instructor does it in class. I tend to copy naming conventions of my instructors when I'm doing an assignment for their class. It just seems to go over better. But thanks for your input. :-)